# i can't add data to bootStrap datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I need additional data on bootstrap data tables and I tried much time.

Data type is JSON object and came from servlet page
`JSONArray[JSONObject{}]`

Server side processing is false(client-side)

I already tried Ajax like this:

```
            $('#mytable').DataTable({
                ajax:{
                    url:'memSearchTable.ad',
                    dataSrc:''
                    },
                    columns:[...]
            });
```

But, it won't work.

This is my script:

```
var data2;
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url:'memSearchTable.ad',
            success:function(data){
                console.log("data : "+data);
                data2 = data;
            }
        });

        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            data:'data2',
            columns: [
                {data:'memNum'},
                {data:'memId'},
                {data:'memName'},
                {data:'memGender'},
                {data:'memPhone'},
                {data:'nationCode'},
                {data:'memPoint'},
                {data:'memType'},
                {data:'memStatus'},
                {data:'enrollDate'},
                {data:'noShow'}
            ]
        });
```

and this is sample of data

```
[
{"memNum":"1",
"memStatus":"Y",
"memName":"ADMIN",
"noShow":"0",
"memPhone":"01012340001",
"memType":"A",
"memGender":"M",
"memPoint":"0",
"enrollDate":"2019-08-29",
"memId":"1","nationCode":"1"},
{"memNum":"2",
"memStatus":"Y",
"memName":"OWNER",
"noShow":"0",
"memPhone":"01012340002",
"memType":"O",
"memGender":"M",
"memPoint":"0",
"enrollDate":"2019-08-29",
"memId":"2",
"nationCode":"2"}
]
```

And I still get "No data available in table" from table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()), I think you should do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'memSearchTable.ad',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#myTable').DataTable().rows.add(data).draw();
        }
    });

    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        data:'data2',
        columns: [
            {data:'memNum'},
            {data:'memId'},
            {data:'memName'},
            {data:'memGender'},
            {data:'memPhone'},
            {data:'nationCode'},
            {data:'memPoint'},
            {data:'memType'},
            {data:'memStatus'},
            {data:'enrollDate'},
            {data:'noShow'}
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: srry still got nothing.